# Problema deshabilitar botón con JS y DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, botón

Estoy tratando de hacer un ejercicio de un trivial básico. Tengo la estructura de datos con 4 preguntas y sus respuestas, y con ello tengo que mostrar por la página:

- Lectura de pregunta
- Cuadro para insertar la solucion
- Botón para comprobar la respuesta (mostrará si es correcta y si no, muestra la solución)
- Siguiente pregunta (generada aleatoriamente).

El caso es que tengo que cuando le doy 3 veces al botón de siguiente pregunta, se tiene que deshabilitar el botón(ya que ya ha mostrado todas las preguntas), pero al implementarlo me da errores y me deshabilita antes...
El código es el siguiente: (ya se que es muy mejorable pero de momento funciona salvo la parte del botón...)

```js
var preguntas = [
  ["¿Cuál es la capital de Austria?", "Viena"], //0,1
  ["¿Cuál es la capital de Noruega?", "Oslo"], // 1,1
  ["¿Qué lengua se habla en Madagascar?", "Malgache"], //2,1
  ["¿Cómo se llaman los habitantes de Panamá?", "Panameños"], //3,1
];

let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
h1.innerHTML = "Responde a las preguntas.";
body.appendChild(h1);

//GENERAR UNA PRIMERA PREGUNTA ALEATORIA.
let preguntaRandom1 = document.createElement("p");
let numRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
preguntaRandom1.innerHTML = preguntas[numRandom][0];
//Hacemos un SET de las preguntas para no repetirlas que nos servirá para no repetir la pregunta cuando cliquemos en siguiente pregunta.
let setPreguntas = new Set();
setPreguntas.add(preguntas[numRandom]);
body.appendChild(preguntaRandom1);

//
let inputRespuesta1 = document.createElement("input");
inputRespuesta1.type = "text";
inputRespuesta1.setAttribute("respuesta", numRandom);
let validarRespuesta1 = document.createElement("input");
validarRespuesta1.type = "button";
validarRespuesta1.value = "Aceptar";
validarRespuesta1.style.marginLeft = "10px";
validarRespuesta1.id = numRandom;

preguntaRandom1.innerHTML = preguntas[numRandom][0] + "    ";
body.appendChild(preguntaRandom1);
preguntaRandom1.appendChild(inputRespuesta1);
let aSolucion = document.createElement("a");
aSolucion.style.margin = "2px";
aSolucion.setAttribute("solucion", numRandom);
preguntaRandom1.appendChild(aSolucion);
preguntaRandom1.appendChild(validarRespuesta1);

//BOTON SIGUIENTE PREGUNTA
let btnSiguiente = document.createElement("input");
btnSiguiente.type = "button";
btnSiguiente.value = "Siguiente pregunta";
btnSiguiente.disabled = false;
btnSiguiente.setAttribute("pregunta", numRandom);
body.appendChild(btnSiguiente);

//Añadimos event listener a boton
btnSiguiente.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.type != "button") return;
  siguientePregunta();
});

//Añadimos event listener al boton de validar respuesta
validarRespuesta1.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.type != "button") return;
  validarRespuesta(e.target.id);
});

//Funcion siguiente pregunta, funcionara hasta que se hayan leido todas las preguntas(no se haya pulsado mas de 3 veces el contador)
let contadorBoton = 0;
function siguientePregunta() {
  //Si el contador del boton es 3, ha mostrado todas las preguntas y se deshabilita. Si no, mostramos otra pregunta aleatoria que no haya salido antes.
  let numRandom2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  if (!setPreguntas.has(preguntas[numRandom2]) && contadorBoton < 3) {
    setPreguntas.add(preguntas[numRandom2]);
    preguntaRandom1.innerHTML = preguntas[numRandom2][0] + "   ";
    inputRespuesta1.setAttribute("respuesta", numRandom2);
    inputRespuesta1.value = "";
    validarRespuesta1.id = numRandom2;
    aSolucion.setAttribute("solucion", numRandom2);
    preguntaRandom1.appendChild(inputRespuesta1);
    preguntaRandom1.appendChild(aSolucion);
    let mensajeSolucion2 = document.querySelector("[solucion]");
    mensajeSolucion2.innerHTML = "";
    preguntaRandom1.appendChild(validarRespuesta1);
    btnSiguiente.setAttribute("pregunta", numRandom2);
    contadorBoton++;
  } else {
    btnSiguiente.disabled = true;
  }
}

//Funcion que validará respuesta en funcion del ID seleccionado.
function validarRespuesta(resID) {
  //Declaramos respuesta como el valor con QuerySelector que nos da el atributo del ID seleccionado
  //El metodo CSS.escape nos permite devolver el valor de ID
  //Si recordamos, realizamos un SetAttribute para implantarlo (inputRespuesta.setAttribute("respuesta", i);)
  let respuesta = document.querySelector("[respuesta=" + CSS.escape(resID) + "]").value;
  let mensajeSolucion = document.querySelector("[solucion=" + CSS.escape(resID) + "]");
  //Si la respuesta es correcta, comparamos con el arrayBidimensional en la 2 posicion, que son las respuestas. Creamos el mensaje que queremos.

  let mensajeP = "";
  let respuestaCorrecta = preguntas[resID][1];
  if (respuesta == respuestaCorrecta) {
    mensajeP = "¡CORRECTO!";
    mensajeSolucion.innerHTML = mensajeP;
    return true;
  } else {
    mensajeP = "Lo sentimos, la respuesta correcta es " + respuestaCorrecta + ".";
    mensajeSolucion.innerHTML = mensajeP;
    return false;
  }
}
```

En que parte podria solucionarlo ? La parte del botón está implementada en la función de siguiente pregunta, pero me es imposible lograr que funcione bien...

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te estás complicado con la elección de las preguntas:

```
function siguientePregunta(){

      let numRandom2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
      if(!setPreguntas.has(preguntas[numRandom2]) && contadorBoton<3){
        setPreguntas.add(preguntas[numRandom2]);
```

La condición del `if` se interpreta como:

> Si `setPreguntas` no tiene `preguntas[numRandom2]`  **Y** `contadorBoton` es menor que 3 entonces...

Es decir, que se tienen que cumplir las dos condiciones o se deshabilita el botón. Si eliges una pregunta al azar y esta ya se ha preguntado, directamente paras.

Podrías hacer lo siguiente: barajar las preguntas antes de empezar y simplemente sacarlas de array, así evitas repeticiones y no necesitas comprobar nada más:

```js
function barajar(array) {
  let posicionActual = array.length;

  while (0 !== posicionActual) {
    const posicionAleatoria = Math.floor(Math.random() * posicionActual);
    posicionActual--;
    //"truco" para intercambiar los valores sin necesidad de una variable auxiliar
    [array[posicionActual], array[posicionAleatoria]] = [
      array[posicionAleatoria], array[posicionActual]];
  }
  return array;
}

let preguntas = [ "pregunta 1","pregunta 2","pregunta 3","pregunta 4","pregunta 5"]

barajar(preguntas);

for (let i=0; i< 3;i++) {
  console.log(preguntas.pop()); //sacamos la última, eliminándola del array
}
```